# How to use an asp.net mvc project capabilities in a different asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use [TicketDesk](https://github.com/NullDesk/ticketdesk) (that is a complete asp.net mvc project) capabilities in a different asp.net mvc project. Please suggest the best way possible to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating TicketDesk is straightforward and doesnt have much server configuration to do. What I had done for my project is run ticketdesk on different port on the same domain while both ticketdesk and my application uses the same DB. Note that this will not work in a web farm.

- Create an IIS Web Site or right-click an existing site and select "Add Application" to create a new Virtual Directory
- Select an existing application pool, or create a new one for use by TicketDesk
- Make sure the application pool uses the integrated mode pipeline
- Make sure the application pool is set for .Net Framework 4.0
- Download the desired precompiled distribution from GitHub releases
- Copy the contents of the zip file into the IIS site's physical folder
- Make sure the application pool user has read access to the web site root folder and all sub-folders (if using the default application pool identity, just grant the '[machine]\users' group the necessary permissions)
- Make sure the application pool user has write access to the /app_data folder
- Edit the web.config in the site's root, and update the TicketDesk connection string to point to your SQL server instance
- Open a web browser, and browse to the web site's root URL
- The first-run-setup page should appear
- Review the settings shown; make sure everything listed is accurate before continuing
- Click the Create database button